# How to change the background color of a JFrame with a button in the Mainframe?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, jpanel

I´ve created a simple warehouse management program for my company and everything is working fine.

But now I am trying to implement a darkmode to my program, that will be 'active' if the user presses the corresponding button in the mainframe of the program.

There are multiple buttons in the Mainframe that open other JFrames. And that´s the point im stuck at.

If I´m trying to change the background-color of one of the JFrames it only works if the JFrame already is open.

Here´s an example:

*Pressing the "Darkmode"-Button in the Mainframe*

```
turnOnDarkmodePanel(EditArticle.edCP);
```

Method:

```
public static void turnOnDarkmodePanel(JPanel panel) {
    panel.setBackground(new Color(18,18,18));
}
```

This will be executed. And while the mainframe is perfectly in darkmode the other JFrames are not until I open them and press the Darkmode button in the mainframe again.

Everything else in the JFrame is working fine - Just the background of the Panel doesnt.

*Additional Code for Buttons in Darkmode (Working on every single button without pressing the darkmode button again after opening the JFrame):*

```
public static void turnOnDarkmode(JButton button) {
    button.setForeground(button_fg);
    button.setBackground(button_dm);
    button.setBorder(null);
    
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent evt) {
            button.setBackground(button_dm_hover);
        }
        
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent evt) {
            button.setBackground(button_dm);
        }
    });
}
```

Anyone knows how I can fix this that the JFrames are effected without opening them first?

PS.: I am new to JAVA and if more code is needed - I will add it.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you could keep a properties file, and use that to set the color whenever you open/reload a JFrame. Then, on clicking the button, alter that properties file to the color you want, and reload your page.

Comment: Generally speaking, you'd be better of using a look and feel delegate which supported dark mode